# Selenium test failing headless, but Passing in Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I open a dialog in a primefaces/jsf application and the dialog window has an input text and dropdown used for searching ...

The selenium test works in head mode for chrome.
But, the dropdown is not selectable when run in headless mode.

Please, see the code below:

```
clickElement(DriverFactory.getFactory().getDriver().findElement(By.id(idPrefix + "_label")));
clickElement(DriverFactory.getFactory().getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='" + idPrefix + "_panel']/div/ul/li[text()='" + selection + "']")));
```

The error message is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate a node using //div[@id='refDataSelForm:fileVersion_panel']/div/ul/li[text()='Current']
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09 13:08:06'
System info: host: 'ONS21861', ip: '10.194.138.207', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementByXPath(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1715)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1711)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1711)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:606)
```

Below is my driver config logic:

```
public WebDriver getDriver()
    {
        if (driver == null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Environment.getProperty("appBrowser").equalsIgnoreCase("headless"))
                {
                    driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME, true);
                    Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                            "./src/test/resources/common/chromedriver.exe");
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            try
            {
                driver.get(Environment.getProperty("appURL"));
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

Please, Any ideas why the search works in head mode selecting the dropdown successfully, BUT not in head mode.

Comment: try to add some Explicit wait

Comment: @aolatom, could you solve this issue?